# Conversion of data with a stringr

Tags: r, string

I have one data sets with name DATA_TEST.This data frame contain 9-observations in character format.You can see table below.

```
#Data
DATA_TEST<-data.frame(
             Ten_digits=c([0503]","01","17","0101","1515110000","NA","1518 00 10 
                         00","152190","1602311100"))
                   DATA_TEST$Ten_digits<-as.character(DATA_TEST$Ten_digits)       
    View(DATA_TEST)
```

[image]

So my intention is to convert this data frame with  a package stringr or other package. Actually the code needs to do a few things. First remove the brackets in the codes. Secondly leave a space between the codes Ex: 1515110000 should be converted to 1515 11 00 00 and also 152190 to 1521 90 etc. In the table below you can see finally what the table should look like.

[image]

So can anybody help me with code how to convert this table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for stringr. `gsub` from base R will do it just fine:

```
#Your data
DATA_TEST<-data.frame(
  Ten_digits=c("[0503]","01","17","0101","1515110000",
               "NA","1518 00 10 00","152190","1602311100"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Remove all punctuation (see ?regex), removes more than just brackes
DATA_TEST$new <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", DATA_TEST$Ten_digits)
#DATA_TEST$new <- gsub("[][]", "", DATA_TEST$Ten_digits) # Removes just square brackets

# Make "NA" strings to real 'NA values'
DATA_TEST$new[DATA_TEST$new == "NA"] <- NA

# Insert spaces
DATA_TEST$new <-
  trimws(
    gsub("^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})?([0-9]{2})?([0-9]{2})?$", 
         "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4", DATA_TEST$new)
  )

print(DATA_TEST)
#     Ten_digits           new
#1        [0503]          0503
#2            01            01
#3            17            17
#4          0101          0101
#5    1515110000 1515 11 00 00
#6            NA          <NA>
#7 1518 00 10 00 1518 00 10 00
#8        152190       1521 90
#9    1602311100 1602 31 11 00
```

If you insist on using `stringr`, then `stringr::str_replace` instead of `gsub` can easily be made to work.

Comment: Thanks.I try this code.Everything is good except line of code for brackets.Namely when I run this code, brackets are again there and first observation [0503] is again with brackets.So please correct if is possible.Thank you in advance

Comment: Now fixed; I mistakenly did not reuse the created DATA_TEST$new in the last step.